# How to match a word ending with uppercase letter and a specific letter?

Tags: regular-expression

I have words like `lblSERINOd` in sentences. Words are separated by white space.

I want to replace the `d` at the end of all such words with `u`. So for example `lblSERINOd` will look like `lblSERINOu`.

I have tried `s/.*\ud /u /g` but Vim says it cannot find `.*\ud`.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do it would be this:

```
:%s/\u\zsd\>/u/g
```

Initially I assumed that the new Vim regex engine (being advertised as "faster, but limited") can't understand `\u` in `:substitute`, but this isn't the case. I *rather* think now that the OP forgot to use `%` and simply searched on the wrong line; this would explain the error message, but of course still needs to be confirmed as "the" cause.

Comment: are you sure about the 're' engine thing? I don't see how this makes a difference.

Comment: Nope, not sure at all ... I did a quick test that didn't work, then re-read about `pattern` in the help file, saw mentioned that the new engine is more limited than the old one, assumed that's the cause ... my first test was rather/possibly flawed

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you may have changed Vim's [`'magic'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27magic%27) option from its default to `'nomagic'`.  You can check this with the command

```
:verbose set magic?
```

As documented at [:help /magic](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2Fmagic), `'nomagic'` causes the `.` in a regexp to be treated as a literal dot instead of the metacharacter meaning "match any character".

I would **highly** recommend leaving this option at its default value.  This is one of a few options that really shouldn't exist and can cause subtle problems in plugins.